# Welcome/Greeting message delay in webchat MS botframework

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I was recently investigating an issue related to a delay in rendering a welcome/greeting message for the first time when webchat is launched. The very first activities network request (before showing the welcome/greeting message) is usually 2-6s long(mostly it's either 2.5s or 5-6s). We are trying to implement this using BotFramework webchat version: 4.10.1 with react (minimizable version).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to load welcome/greeting message faster than the current time and upon checking the performance profile I found that activities network request(directline.botframework.com/v3/directline.../activites) is taking either ~2.5s or ~5.5s and after that, there is some more buffer time in between before the welcome message gets rendered.

I tried to record the performance profile of both cases(2.5s/5-6s)

2.5s
https://i.imgur.com/InEyHxl.gif

5s
https://i.imgur.com/yl3l6Z8.gif

Trying to find more information on how to improve/fix this behavior and gain more insights on this. I would be really glad if anyone can share your thoughts on this issue. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Is this happening with every new conversation or only when the bot has been idle for awhile with no new conversations occurring? If the latter, be sure to enable "Always on" in the bot's app service configuration.

Comment: Also, are there any error or warning messages being generated in the browser's dev console? For instance, posting to Direct Line failed or there was a delay/time out issue?

Comment: this happens only once when we launch the bot first time and no error or warnings in console log. new version update helped with the performance issue. we are able to get things up in 2s now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug that should be solved in a more recent version of webchat

[bugreport in github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3431)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. got rid of 5s case. max load time is 2s now ))